# PHP Discussion - pass parameters as array or a "Configuration" Class

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm

First, if this question doesn't belong here (and there is a better place for it), let me know.

Second, I'm asking this question about "code quality", not "performance".

Third, This isn't really related to PHP but as each laguage have their "Good Practices", I prefer specify it.

Finally, if there is a similar question, sorry about that, I didn't find it.

Now the Question:

Is it better to have a method parameter as array or as a `"Configuration"` class ?

For example, I'm working with Doctrine and in my Reporsitory, i often have one method that accepts "criteria" and another method `prepareCriteria` that use the `$criteria` array to build the `QueryBuilder`.

And the more I work with array in these cases, the more I wonder if it wouldn't be better to have some `CriteriaBuilder` (or `CriteriaConfiguration` or whatever) to completely control the typing of the parameters passed and not rely on simple string key of an array.

What are your thoughts about that ?

ps: I don't really knwo what tags can be fitted to this sort of question.
I added `doctrine` as I'm talking about it as example, but if you have more precise tags that could be used, let me know.

Comment: But really your 'configuration' class will just be a fancy array. I try to stay away from to many levels of abstraction, you keep going and you'll have 10 classes to just handle an array. CriteriaBuilderMessageHookHandler would be there somewhere :) Keep it simple

Comment: Your question indeed doesn't belong here because it's Primarily Opinion-based. What is better? Who decides that? How is anyone able to answer your question with facts and not personal opinion? And in the end it'll be your personal opinion on which is the "best" answer unsupported by any facts. That's the reason why it's an off-topic question.

Comment: I don't know where the propper place for this Q could be, however, here 'primarily opinion-based' questions shall be voted to be closed. PHP is a pain. Usually a class would be better practice to prevent bugs due to typos when creating assoc arrays. However, that's much overhead in large projects. There's no really good alternative yet, except using binary flag constants for a set of boolean options.

Comment: Class declarations in PHP do not prevent instances from implicitly declare further properties, even from outside. Using magic method `__set` is expensive and annoying. There are no simple initializers like in C# `new MyClass(){prop1="foo", prop2="bar"}` You have to write a constructor which does not provide named properties on invokation like Perl, but only positional parameters - not very readable. Again, PHP is a pain.

Comment: To get more on-topic, you might want to edit your question and ask something like: "What is a reliable way to pass some complex configuration settings?"  You can show two examples of passing an array and an object. You should stay on PHP as language since depend on language specifications different practices are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The probably best practice in PHP is to use verbose associative arrays and string [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) with only a small overhead when assertions are disabled on production systems or as of PHP7 even *expections* with zero cost. It's annoying when writing code but readable on later code reviews and also discovering errors when testing code at development time.

Just to show an example:

**php.ini**

```
zend.assertions  = 1
assert.warning   = 1
assert.exception = 1
assert.bail      = 1
```

**PHP**

```
function foobar(array $config)
{    
  assert
  (
    (function($keys_allowed, $keys_expected)use($config)
    {
      // do not stop execution until all issues are output
      $opt_expt = assert_options(ASSERT_EXCEPTION, 0);
      $opt_bail = assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL     , 0);

      $ok = 1;

      $ok &= assert( empty( $diff = array_diff_key(array_fill_keys($keys_expected, 1), $config) ),
                     new AssertionError('Missing mandatory keys: (' . join(', ', array_keys($diff)) . ')'));

      $ok &= assert( empty( $diff = array_diff_key($config, $keys_allowed) ),
                     new AssertionError('Disallowed keys: (' . join(', ', array_keys($diff)) . ')'));

      $ok &= assert( empty( $diff = array_filter
                                    ( $config,
                                      function($v, $k)use($keys_allowed)
                                      {
                                        return isset($keys_allowed[$k]) && $keys_allowed[$k] !== gettype($v);
                                      },
                                      ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
                                    ),
                     new AssertionError('Type error on items: (' . join(', ', array_keys($diff)) . ')'));

      //restore configured behaviour    
      assert_options(ASSERT_EXCEPTION, $opt_expt);
      assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL     , $opt_bail);
      return $ok;
    })
    (
      [ 'foo' => 'string', 'bar' => 'integer', 'baz' => 'boolean' ],   [ 'baz' ]
    )
    , new AssertionError('Arguments assertion in function `' . __FUNCTION__ . '` failed.')
  );


  // foobar function stuff
  echo 'Ok!', PHP_EOL;
}

// test
foobar(['foo' => '1',              'baz' => true                     ] );  // Ok!
foobar([              'bar' => 1 , 'baz' => true                     ] );  // Ok!


foobar(['foo' => 1  ,              'baz' => true                     ] );  // Warning: type ; Fatal error
foobar(['foo' => '1', 'bar' => 1                                     ] );  // Warning: missing ; Fatal error
foobar(['foo' => 1  , 'bar' => '1'               , 'forbidden' => 'x'] );  // Warnings: missing, disallowed, type ; Fatal error
```

The outer assertion throws a fatal error stopping the execution while the inner assertions throw non-breaking warnings.

You can easily transform the anonymous function into a named function taking the used variable as additional parameter.